# SymmetricDS: How to use external select with subselet router?

Tags: symmetricds

I have a table structure like below :

```
ID | State | StoreID |Description
1  | A     | 001     | Store 001
2  | A     | 002     | Store 002
3  | B     | 003     | Store 003
```

For store 001 and 002, it belong to same state, so when it sync to node 001 or 002, it should have row ID 1 and 2, based on the state where node id is.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   table1 
WHERE  State IN (
  SELECT State 
  FROM table1 
  WHERE StoreID = node_id
)
```

Can I use external select to save the State data for future use ?

Comment: My problem is I can't get my node_id in subselect

Comment: where's the `node_id` coming from?

Comment: I just put there to explain I want to send to the specific target node id, but I can't think of a way to get that.

Comment: Look at my answer to your previous question

Comment: I modify it to be : c.external_id in (
select StoreID from table1 where State = (select State from table1 where State =:STATE and StoreID =:STOREID
)

Comment: But I noticed my delete action was not synced. In outgoing batch, the node_id is -1.

Comment: It's the trigger declared to be on delete as well?

Comment: Yes it is sync on delete = 1.

Comment: It means there's no registered node that matches subselect expression's results.

Comment: Yes. Why it is like that ? Is it because :COLUMN already delete from source so it can't find ?

Comment: Check the sym_data last inserted rows and there are the exact deleted values in row_data

Comment: SYM_DATA got the delete event. It looks OK, only outgoing batch show node_id -1

Comment: Find the data used for the routing from sym_data and insert it into the subselect expression to see what's the result

Comment: what do you mean to insert into subselect expression ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46805868/symmetricds-how-to-use-external-select-with-subselet-router#comment80595707_46805868

Comment: the source already deleted. the target still have.

Comment: I modify it to use soft delete, transform delete to update its status. This workaround work for me. https://gist.github.com/chenson42/d4da303bb8a8dcc0ef00